# Update dependencies while in hosted mode in GWT

Tags: maven, gwt, gwt-hosted-mode

I have a GWT webapp split into two Maven projects where one is a dependency to the other. Each time I change something in the dependency and I'm running webapp in hosted mode I have to rebuild the subproject and restart hosted mode for changes to apply. It takes a lot of time so I'd like to ask you if there is any way to make GWT using "live" version of the dependency?

Comment: How are you running the DevMode? and is your issue about client-side or server-side code?

Comment: I'm running hosted mode with mvn gwt:run. The dependency is another GWT client-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 cases:

- for server-side code, assuming you use the DevMode's embedded server, rebuilding the app and then *refreshing the server* should be enough
- for client-side code, AFAICT, you have to use the source and output directories of the dependency module rather than the JAR containing them (GWT will load the source from the classpath, but apparently it'll only see the modified sources if it comes from a folder rather than a JAR; at least that's what I found in my tests). This goes against [The Maven Way™](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/04/the-maven-way.html) but the only solution so far is to use a special profile that will *import* the sources of the dependency project as sources of the project you're running. You can see examples of that in [my archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes).

  There's actually a bug opened for the `gwt-maven-plugin`, [MGWT-332](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-332), to do that automatically when running a reactor build. I also [mused](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin/wiki/DevModeDesignDoc) about what's really needed, for the forthcoming official `gwt-maven-plugin` (rewritten from scratch, independent from the CodeHaus Mojo plugin).

  If your dependency does not come from a reactor build, then you're out on your own: you chose to make it totally distinct, so that's how it'll behave: you'll have to release it (even a snapshot) each time you make a change to it, and use the new version in your app (which means re-launching the DevMode).

  This can be circumvented by running DevMode on your own, without the help of the `gwt-maven-plugin`. You're left on your own managing the classpath though (using the Google Plugin for Eclipse, I suppose you could simply edit the launch configuration to add the source folders of your dependency project to the classpath, before the classpath provided by Maven, that would reference the JAR).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dependent other application jar file from the primary application lib folder under webapp. 
Eclipse should then resolve the dependency using the other project in the workspace if you have added it to your primary application classpath.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans, but the dependency is already a project (not jar file).

Answer (score 0):

As GWT build takes ages, we invested some money in a JRebel license. We have two separate Eclipse projects for our back-end and our GWT front-end. JRebel reloads the classes automatically and I never need to restart my local server while writing code. It proved to be a wonderful time saver. Definitely worth the investment.